# Bootstrap resampling from gaussian distribution.

Tags: statistics, bootstrap-sampling

I have a set of points $\{x_i,y_i\}$ with 20 elements on the scatter plot, the distribution looks like Gaussian. My goal is to estimate the Gaussian center $x_{center}=\mu$ of this distribution. I'm trying to apply the bootstrapping method by sampling 20 elements with replacement each time and find the average of each sample. I'll repeat this procedure many times to get a small distribution of average.

My question is since my original dataset might not be a normal distribution, should I normalize the probability $y_i$ and use that as weight in my resampling of $x_i$? If so, in the output distribution of average, how can I determine its peak as my estimation? Is it just the highest bar?

Thanks:)

Comment: You have $20$ observations of the form $(x_i, y_i)$, however you are interested only in $x_i$ and its mean $\mu$? If so, it is not clear how you use $y_i$.

Comment: @V. Vancak Thanks for the comment! Yes I have 20 observations that are distributed like a Gaussian peak on the scatter plot. I'm interested in finding the center of the peak.

Comment: So are you interested in $(\mu_X, \mu_y)$, i.e., two dimensional parameter?

Comment: @V. Vancak No, $\{x,y\}$ are distributed like a Gaussian peak on the plot, they are not gaussian random values. y represents some probability, so I wonder if I could determine the Gaussian center on the x-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard practice is taking the (unweighted) average of the BS sample, i.e.,
let $w_i$ be the weight of the $x_i$, hence for each sample you have
$$
\mu_{b} = \sum_{i=1}^{20} w_i x_i,
$$
for $b=1,...,B$, where $B$ is the number of BS samples. Then the BS point estimator is
$$
\mu_B = \frac{1}{B}\sum_{b=1}^B \mu_b.
$$
In your case it should correspond to the "peak" of the BS-based sample distribution.

Comment: Thanks! Does $B$ represent how many BS samples we want to have?

Comment: Should $\mu_b$ be divided by 20?

Comment: 1. True, $B$ is the number of BS samples, 
2. No, $\mu_b$ is already weighted. If $\mu_b$ is unweighted then $w_i = 1/20$ and thus you divide by $20$, however in your case the weights are $$  w_i = \frac{y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{20}y_i} $$

Comment: So should $x_i$ in the equation of $\mu_B$ be sampled with replacement? If so, $w_i$ should be the weight calculated from my original data, right? (Not BS sample)

Comment: Yes, with replacement. And yes, the $w_i$ are calculated from the original $y_1,..,y_{20}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can I take the error bar of this estimation to be half of the 95% confidence interval?

Comment: If the error bars are one $\pm$ standard deviation, then yes. You're welcome!